# "AssignmentOperator Expression" error on simple lambda expression code

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning how to use lambda expressions now, and I've seen some tutorials with a simple example:

```
(int x) -> x + 5;
```

But my compiler is showing this error:

```
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the lambda, and Java's syntax tries to exclude statements that obviously don't do anything.

Comment: What are you expecting that code to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lambda expressions always have to be assigned to a reference type of Functional Interafces** (also called single abstract method interfaces). Infact, they provide shortcut to the verbose anonymous class (with single method) implementations.

So, in simple words, Lambda expression = abstract method implementation (of the functional interface).

For example, your expression can be assigned to the below Functional Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {//define Functional Interafce (SAM)
    public int someMethod(int a);
}

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface myInterface = (int a) -> a +5;//assign the expression to SAM
        int output = myInterface.someMethod(20)); //returns 25
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Lambdas are expressions that cannot be used as statements. From [JLS8 §15.27](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27):

> It is a compile-time error if a lambda expression occurs in a program in someplace other than an assignment context (§5.2), an invocation context (§5.3), or a casting context (§5.5).

Consider this example:

```
// functional interface
interface Operator
{  
  int apply(int a, int b);
}  
// method that expects instance of the interface
int calculate(int a, int b, Operator op)
{  
  return op.apply(a, b);
}  
// lambda expression
Operator plus = (a, b) -> a + b; 
// method call
calculate(40, 2, plus);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, as pointed out above, you are not doing anything with the lambda. This means that:

- the compiler does not know which functional interface (e.g. java.util.function.Function) to infer as the type for your lambda.

  Your line of code is "not a statement" (another error message often emitted by the compiler). This is similar to something like this:

`"Hello";`

Which is not valid Java.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression cannot stand alone in Java, it need to be associated to a functional interface.

```
public interface myinterface
    {
        int mymethod(int a,int b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {                     
            myinterface my = ( a,b ) -> { 
                int mul = a*4;
                int add = a+b;
                return add; };

    }
```

**Note**: This is the first and last time you will see implemention of interface without keyword **"Implements"**.

**Play Around:** try adding a new dummy method to your interface `myinterface` and you will see that your code will fail to compile, thus indicating that reference has to be only made from **Functional interface** not from general interfaces.

```
public interface myinterface
    {
        int mymethod(int a,int b);
        int newmethod(String j);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            myinterface my = ( a,b ) -> { 
            int mul = a*4;
            int add = a+b;
            return add;
        };
```

> Compilation Error: *The target type of this expression must be a
>   functional interface*